# Is there a website where I can check reports on issues in a daycare in South Carolina?

Tags: daycare

Recently my daycare in South Carolina sent me a report regarding unattended child incident happened in another room. I am wondering is there a single resource that makes all of those reports accessible to the public? Thanks!

Comment: As Vicky points out, this question does not specify what country our childcare system the OP is looking for, and I don't believe this question is answerable without that information.  @olenak, please edit the question to provide more details, and reply in comments or flag for moderator attention once you've done so.

Comment: thank you for providing additional information.  I've expanded your question slightly, so that the answers don't have to be exclusively websites.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the site you want: http://www.scchildcare.org/

You can input a city or zipcode, and it will list all of the child care providers in the area. You can click on any one to see the complaints and whether they have been resolved. Some of them are a bit cryptic to understand. From my perusal of various SC child care sites, it would appear that facilities are only inspected if people complain.

According to [Child Care Aware](http://www.naccrra.org/node/2494) (NACCRRA), "Child care center licensing and oversight in South Carolina ranked 50th in a ranking of all states, including the District of Columbia and the Department of Defense."

[This page](http://childcareaware.org/node/1402?field_categories_value_many_to_one=All&field_state_select_value_many_to_one=SC) from NACCRRA has some additional links to information on child care licensing in South Carolina.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said where you are located, which makes a difference - there's certainly no global daycare incidence report site but different countries / regions may run their own.

In the UK, any incidents resulting in a child being taken to A&E (ER) have to be reported to Ofsted, the education watchdog. However they [do not collate](http://www.nurseryworld.co.uk/article/1166424/exclusive-concern-lack-data-nursery-deaths-injuries) or centrally record these and they are not generally made available. The nursery's [Ofsted inspection report](http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/inspection-reports/find-inspection-report), a general report on standards at the nursery, would be the closest thing you would get.